# How is bash's * passed to a program?

Tags: bash

When I type `evince *` in a folder with a lot of pdfs, what is sent to evince? Does evince receive X arguments, or are X occasions of evince opened, each one getting one argument (a single file)?

Comment: Use `echo evince *` to see result of bash's globbing.

Answer (score 1):

Bash performs shell expansion on each command line. One of those expansions is [filename expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion) which replaces `*` according to [pattern matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching) rules.

In case of `evince *`, it replaces the `*` with content of current working directory. The content means names of regular files, sub-directories, links etc. Dot-files are excluded. Basically what you get from running `ls`. In your case filenames of PDFs.

Therefore, the `evince` binary gets executed by Bash only once with arguments being alphabetically-orderded filenames contained in current working directory. The way Evince handles its launch afterwards is up to Evince or whatever framework or library it depends on, but barebones X doesn’t do anything special here. Evince or X even don’t know it got executed with `*`. For example:

```bsh
$ ls -a
. .. .hiddendoc.pdf doc1.pdf doc2.docx otherdoc.pdf somedir
$ evince *
# is equivalent to
$ evince doc1.pdf doc2.docx otherdoc.pdf somedir
```

If you want to know how `*` gets expanded, just run `echo *`. You may notice that if the working directory is empty (contains only dot-files), the asterisk isn’t expanded and stays as argument for command execution.

As mentioned in the linked Bash manual, there are number of settings which change this behavior. Not to mention other shells.

Comment: Right.  If user has any question, user can run "echo *", and that will show just what filenames the * will turn into.